# Comment after you downvote and stop commenting +1 after you upvote

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes, up-votes

Site is now generating quality content, but few users are complaining that others users are down voting their post and are not providing any reason to do so.

On the other hand am seeing lot of users commenting `+1, Nice question`, `+1, Nice answer`.

#### So

**Don't Comment +1, Nice question, Excellent quetion, just up vote if you like the question**

We don't need to comment everytime we see a nice post, for that clicking an upvote button is more than sufficient. The comment are of no use to the post, if you have any interesting detail to add, edit the post or comment on the question, but please don't litter around comments which are of no use. Hover the up vote button and it will show

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

So we don't have to repeat the same thing by commenting them. If you want to comment, comment something useful, like improvement suggestions, share related answers by which users asking questions may get more information.

Read what the placeholder of the comment box says

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.
>   Avoid answering questions in comments.

---

**Comment after you down vote - suggestion to improve the post or whats wrong in the post**

**Now should I comment everytime I down vote?**

**NO**, you don't have to. We know that some posts are low quality and in no way we can make them better even after editing, so in such cases, you can down vote them without providing any reason to do so, because when you hover the down vote button, it says

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful

But if it is not only about research effort, unclear or useful, you can comment on the answer suggesting an improvement to the post or say whats wrong with the post and what a user can do in order to fix it.

---

**Why comment after you down vote?**

- Users will get a reason of your down vote and accordingly they will rectify their post
- We will get more accurate content on the site if they improve their posts
- Users will appreciate if you provide reasons instead of anonymously down voting, else it demotivates them