# Downvoting decent posts without comments

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

I am seeing this happening recently that there is down vote trend even on fairly decent and well researched post.
Here are some examples : [Post-1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11331/is-vishnus-incarnation-dattatreya-quoted-in-the-brahma-sutras), [Post-2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11217/why-rama-is-not-depicted-as-ajanubahu%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%81-in-idol-pictures)

**Even worse, there is no mention of reason as to why they down voted the post.**

Of course, **you don't have to give** a reason for **every** down vote, since some posts are so low in quality and in no way we can make them better even after editing, so in such cases, we can down vote them without providing any reason. This is **already** [discussed in meta.hinduism](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235/comment-after-you-downvote-and-stop-commenting-1-after-you-upvote)

The example I mentioned are by no way can be called as low quality posts (one of them is my own, where I added all the references from valid sources as per this site's rule while composing the post).

Of course, my **worry** is not the down vote itself(and loosing the reputation as a consequence of it), but this habit of fairly senior and expericed community members to down vote fairly well searched post without even pointing out reasons/comments.

As a community, how can we deal with this situation?

Comment: I hope, you don't mind editing your question.

Comment: @AnkitSharma That's Ok. I guess the intention was to only bring it to notice to the community of this -ve trend that I observed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meta is where we work as community, so here our discussion should be how to resolve the issue rather then blaming each other. I appreciate your meta post and your concern but the way it's going doesn't suit the discussion and might even kill your good intention behind it. So i have taken out some part of your question and even removed the answer (I appreciate both user for coming forward) because it's not we are here gathered for.

We did noticed few cases of [target voting](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/518/complaint-targeted-downvoting-on-my-posts), but it's auto reversed now. Whenever there is some target voting (even upvote) then it get reversed automatically by some undisclosed daily process, so we don't need to get worry about it.

Read [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com//help/serial-voting-reversed) for details about voting correction.

Even overall target voting get notified to moderators too. So we will handle it if it appeared.

I do agree that downvote should be presented with a proper reasoning, as a comment or even upvoting already present comment if applicable. But we can't force user to do so, there is auto pop-up suggestion for it but it's to guide not to force.

We can't here see who specifically downvoted your or someone's post, so guessing who had done it and name dropping is completely unethical as they might not be the one who done it. We can do one thing, we can upvote good post and compensate for the downvote, do remember downvote = -2 and upvote = +10. It's not about reputation but also to show how helpful the post is.

If you still feel someone target voting on someone, feel free to flag that post, as flags are not public and we moderator can help you to resolve them. One more thing both post still hold single down-vote that means they were not targeted vote as they didn't got reversed.

Comment: somehow I feel that, my post was assumed to be highlighting target voting. But No, that is not the case. I wanted to attract the attention to the fact that even fair post are downvoted without commenting, most likely by Sr.members within community. That is worrying Trend for the well being of community.

Comment: @WhisperingMonk I can understand your concern, will surely look into it if anything fishy happen again.

Comment: Sure, thanks! With you Joining the moderation team, community should feel at ease as now we  have more than 1 Active Moderator!