# Complaint-Targeted downvoting on my posts

Tags: support, down-votes

There is a continuous 12 downvotes on my 12 posts at about the same time.So i suspect foul play here.

[image]

Most of the questions are valid and the answers which were downvoted are correct too.But that of course doesn't matter in case of a foul play.

I don't know if this is the proper way of bringing a problem to Moderators' notice but currently i don't know of any other way.

Anyways, i want Moderators to intervene.

I'm also surprised to see why a relatively new user like me is being targeted.

If this thing gonna continue then obviously there's no point in continuing being active.

Also,i will not be active for few more days from now.I apologize to some users to whom i am not able to reply for that reason.

Comment: Please do not reduce your activity just because some user is serially downvoting you - I've been serially downvoted lots of times.  In any case, there's an automated script that runs everyday looking for serial voting and reversing it.  So wait 24 hours or so and see if you get your points back.

Comment: I think i know who downvoted but i don't know why.

Comment: @Rickross The voting system is deliberately anonymous. Trying to guess who is using it (or in this case abusing it) is not constructive and the best thing you can do is leave it along and walk away. The abuse will get fixed and nothing good will come of you trying to do anything about the abuser. Let the mods take care of anything that needs doing at this point.

Comment: All the down votes were casted about an hour ago.And among the voters who mostly voted in current week there's one user who's last seen time  is also about 1 hour ago and who's rep points are decreasing without any of his own posts receiving any down votes.So he is the one who down voted.But this assumption of mine is based on the info found on another meta post which states that we can know the top voters for a week,month etc.Also with each downvote u cast u loose 1 rep point.So i guess i'm right?

Comment: @Caleb There is nothing i can or i will do against the abuser.But i'm really surprised to see that he is doing all this.

Comment: @Rickross Read my comment again. I didn't say there weren't edge cases where people give themselves away, but I did say **it is not constructive to sleuth around and try to figure it out**. Stop it. Walk away. Your account will be taken care of and by pursing this (and now leaving a trail of drama for others to follow) you'll just make a bad situation worse. Let the moderators deal with it from here out.

Comment: If it doesn't revert for you, flag any of your post for mods attention and mention this issue and moderators will handle those serial votes reversal.

Comment: @Mr.Alien The serial votes have been reversed .Thanks for the help.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Can system detect if there are  only a couple of serial targeted votes?I think it can only detect when the number of such votes is greater than a particular number like say 10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to do anything actually, just wait ~24 hours. The SE engine routinely scans vote history for patterns like this and that will almost certainly get reverted shortly.