# Concerns about brigading

Tags: discussion, faq, voting, community

Lately, it seems there has been a tendency for some users to group together and compulsively upvote posts that adhere to a certain viewpoint or posts by certain users that uphold this viewpoint or downvote posts that throw shade -either blatantly or subtly-  on viewpoints that are in opposition to theirs.

What is SE's and HSE's stand on brigading?

[Return to FAQ index](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478)

Comment: This is speculation. Upvoting and downvoting a post is user's personal choice. There is no proof that there is brigading or groups. You don't know who are upvoting and who is downvoting.

Comment: @NogShine true. I as a user don't know who is upvoting or downvoting but Mods or SE will. If there is concern about brigading, I'd like to hear steps SE takes to counter it.

Comment: No, even moderators won't know who is upvoting and downvoting. Only the employess of SO can see it when there's some illegal style of voting. Unless there is illegal, it will be caught by the system.

Comment: Even if some people do that i don't think there is any way to stop it.@moonstar

Comment: Anyways mods are the best persons to answer this one.

Comment: This is unfortunately true but I don't think anything can be done about it. We can't stop users from voting, this is a subtle point like the interpolation post, we know it's wrong but can't do anything about it.

Comment: I got some points restored by the system with the message "serial voting was reversed". Is that the same thing?

Comment: @SK No that's different. This is different. Your case- Someone targeted you and downvoted ur random posts. That's illegal to do. System automatically will reverse it. Has happened with me too  See this: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/518/complaint-targeted-downvoting-on-my-posts

Comment: What is the meaning of making this question a "faq"? @Pandya

Comment: @Rickross Unfortunately our community has been facing the issue of blind secterian voting. So, this post would guide users towards the voting ethics.

Comment: @Pandya People will still vote. No way of stopping them. If u say to smokers "Don't smoke" will they stop smoking? NO, it does not work like that..

Answer (score 13):

<sup>Note: In addition to cover the question has asked, I felt to address some relevant issues and hence posting a general answer:</sup>

Hinduism StackExchange is **not** like a game show or popularity contest. The site is not here to dictate or define the views of it's users. The goal is to provide reliable information about Hinduism rather than debating among the beliefs or philosophies.

One should not upvote the post just because his or her personal philosophy or doctoral belief agrees with it. Instead one should cast upvote if the post is quality, well written and researched, backed up with sources and useful to visitors; even if you may disagree with the doctrine or philosophy presented. In brief, **Voting should be done on quality and usefulness of posts, not on the doctoral agreement.**

Otherwise, such voting based only on the agreement rather than the quality of post would make the voting system like a popularity contest which would be dangerous or unhealthy for the community since such activity highly deviates the goal of Hinduism StacExchange.

We know that among all the religions, Hinduism has very much diversity, there are various beliefs and philosophies. The problem we often face is due to the difference in thoughts and beliefs or different Sampradaya. Let me tell you that proving particular beliefs superior than others is not the objective of this site. We should respect all Sampradyaya, their beliefs and philosophies I've already pointed [Please stay away from Shiva vs. Vishnu debate](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1033/277). Btw, I remember we also had a post [Please try to appreciate others' views, answers and perspectives - even if you don't agree!](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/711/277)

Also note that [We should encourage the community to answer in the same alignment to the question.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/106/33362) It means "the questions should be answered specifically within the context of the belief system they are asked."

This issue is quite common on religious sites, you're recommended to visit relevant posts on other sites which passed from similar situations:

- [Please vote based on quality](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/982)
- [Is it acceptable to “vote your convictions” on Christianity.SE?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3716/33362)
- [How do we avoid a vote contest?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/122/33362)
- [Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275)

Comment: "Hinduism StackExchange is not like a game show or popularity contest. The site is not here to dictate or define the views of it's users. The goal is to provide reliable information about Hinduism rather than debating among the beliefs or philosophies." - if you really mean those things, you need to add those to the [site info / on-topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.