# Why is comment deleted, which was pointing out mistake in an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-question

This question is about [Who is the goddess depicted as "Bharat Mata" & why is she having Indian tricolor flag?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28670/5212) and the comments posted under it. There are problems with on-topicness of the question, but it's a different discussion.

An [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/28679/5212) was posted to that question, saying Bharat Mata is Goddess Durga. I posted a comment to the OP asking not to accept a wrong answer and pointed out that Bharat Mata is not a Hindu figure. I also suggested to discourage answers to a question once it is known that it is off-topic. Then I also said that, what is wrong in the answer. Later, the comment was deleted.

As far as I know, there is nothing wrong in pointing out the mistakes in comments. I have not crossed the limits of [Code of Conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct) too. The answer was not edited to make the comments obsolete. I even got a reply from the OP about the comment. **The reply existed, the other reply from other user also existed** but my comment asking question to OP and the user who posted the answer, was removed.

**Why is comment deleted which was pointing out that answer is wrong**?
(I didn't take a pic of it as I didn't expect it to be deleted as it was pointing out wrong in the answer)

---

P.S: I am not getting satisfied with the explanation "Users are flagging it. What can I do?" from the moderator. Moderators have an option to decline a flag if the raised flags are wrong.

Comment: It was deleted by community and no mod was involved in it.

Comment: @TheDestroyer The question is why. I already added in the note that users flagged and no moderators involved is not I am looking for. A moderator can reverse the wrong flags of users. Closing now has no effect as it already got accepted answer and free rep. It is not going to delete automatically by Community. :/ Moreover the answer is controversial.

Comment: @Pandya I don't know. There was an upvoted comment by me and it is not yet visible for me. From iammilind's answer's it is clear that it is flagged. But from Destroyer's comment, it is known that no mod deleted it. What is happening? The answer is wrong and controversial. Such answers are not good for the site. As far as I know we don't encourage controversies here. Am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do we do with the comments which give wrong information and posted on wrong assumptions?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/what-do-we-do-with-the-comments-which-give-wrong-information-and-posted-on-wrong)

Comment: @TheDestroyer I am waiting from the answer from moderators. Why is the comment deleted by community? clearly, the comment was not noise.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma "Why is the comment deleted by community?" Because users flagged it. "clearly, the comment was not noise". Well we can only decide on this if we really know whether question is on-topic or off-topic (i see community is divided on this). You are imposing your view on OP strongly and that comment is not needed.

Comment: @TheDestroyer There were many things in the comment and not only whether the question is on topic or off-topic. There are mistakes in the answers. Imposing view on OP? where? Discouraging answers to off-topic questions is my personal view? It is SE's view. The flagger didn't like it. OP also thought it is off-topic. Hence I said like that. One should educate new users. If they do, they say imposing views. :/ If I am going to get the answer "users flagged it" for every comment I asked, some 3 users might form a gang and flag every comment they don't like.They will be automatically deleted.

Comment: You should read [Code of Conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct) which says "Be kind and friendly - Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online. **If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on.**" The language you used to OP was unfriendly and comes under Unacceptable Behavior.

Comment: The answer on the question you linked "Yes, we should be mindful of how we express ourself, and think about how our words could be interpreted" That's exactly what draws line between friendly and unfriendly. You could and should have worded your words differently.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I just said voting and accepting answers to off-topic questions is discouraged. It is not unfriendly or rude to get deleted. Did you flag my comment as unfriendly? Based on what? Can you say the unfriendly words in the comment? My words were proper and neutral tone. If flagers have a prejudice, I have nothing to say. I know what I was saying.

Answer (score 5):

**Because the comment was creating NOISE**.
I had flagged your comment under my answer with following:

> > User is imposing own thinking on OP without any credible source. In the Qn section, it's already debated that the question is on-topic. Without any meta discussion or proof, this comment is noise.

---

There are many of your comments under the question of similar tone as the deleted comment which is now inaccessible, so putting one of them for the reference:

> > <sub>The question is its on-topicness. This is not a question of Hinduism but a country. Our site is not confined to a country. She is not a religious figure or a goddess to encourage a question about her. She is "mother". Answering off-topic questions is a bad. It only encourages more and more questions like these. practice I don't believe a statement from scripture, how can I believe a false statement from wiki?</sub> Your answer is wrong and contradicts reality. It may stir up controversy as it is limiting Bharat mata to a single religion. Don't do such things. It affects site's credibility as well.  [[comment]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28670/who-is-the-goddess-depicted-as-bharat-mata-why-is-she-having-indian-tricolor/28679#comment84526_28670)

If answer is wrong then downvote and move on. What do you mean by "single religion". This site is only about "Hinduism". What has this question to do with the reality, controversy, site credibility etc.? Such fears are misplaced.

Though OP had accepted my answer, later it seems he reversed it considering constant pressure from you in so many comments. OP urged you:

> > @Sarvabhouma please don't try to criticise me, After having a conversation with you, I myself had hit the flag to delete my question, someone tries to give me answer on I ask a question and I feel this is really clear my doubts then I accepted, What did I do wrong?  [[comment]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28670/who-is-the-goddess-depicted-as-bharat-mata-why-is-she-having-indian-tricolor/28679#comment84535_28670)

IMO, the OP who is only 4 months into the site, may have felt threatened by bitter user experience being created by too many comments. Must be Avoided in future. **One should not be dictating the terms to other users of what to accept and what to vote**. Even Mods also don't interfere these much. Just keep the user informed via chatroom in a non-commanding way.

---

It's worth discussing the OP's post to be opened/closed, because all your comments are founded on an assumption that the question itself is off topic.
Here are few points to show why it's On-topic:

- The depiction of "Bharat mata" is identical to many goddesses and hence it's natural curiosity if such goddess exists or not; Even one answer says "NO" as well
- There is a temple in Benaras, which is inaugurated by [saintly figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Dee_Hame_Azaadi) - Mahatma Gandhi, who was also part of independence movement
- We cannot compare her with other figures trivially due to her history of reverence for several decades if not centuries
- The question is not about "India" or "Bharat"; rather it just happens to be associated with culture and geographical identity; "Hindu" is also geographical identity at its core; & we are in "Hinduism.SE"
- Tags [culture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) and [history](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) suit such questions

We all have mismatch of opinions in open/close of posts. But in this case, I feel pity for those who closed this particular question -- ironically on the independence day!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81869/discussion-on-answer-by-iammilind-why-is-comment-pointing-out-mistake-in-an-answ).