# How to find out whether valid reference is actually valid or not for giving answer?

Tags: discussion, sources-and-citations

I have given an [answer here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21776/was-there-ever-a-time-when-i-was-not-there) with all valid(I guess) reference that I could find in support of my answer. But still I received down votes!! I don't mind if anyone gives down votes to my answer. I am always ready to accept my mistake if any.

But issue here is that no one specified what was wrong in my answer! Here I am confused about where I went wrong. Because I did add all valid reference and all reference from this site only.

Only one person tried to explain reason via one shloka from Veda. But when I contradict his shloka to ask that how this shloka is proving my answer wrong.. then he had no answer. Means, his mentioned shloka wasn't able to prove my answer wrong.

> My questions are...

1. How would I know which reference should I take to post answer on
   this site?
2. The references I linked was from other answers of this site only, and
   if those other answers didn't get negative response then why my
   answer is getting negative response?
3. On what cases an answer with full of references can get down votes?

**Note**: I would have not asked this question here if I don't have believe that I added only valid references in my answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your main grievance seems to be the fact that despite adding valid references in your answer it still got downvoted. Then, that is quite normal to happen here. Many of our answers too got plenty of downvotes despite having sources and valid sources.

For example [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19754/4732) of mine, although accompanied with valid sources, got as many as 5 downvotes.

Similarly, Tezz's [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15257/4732) got equal number of downvotes although it too has valid references.

And, there are numerous such instances.

So, having valid references in the answer does not really safeguard it from being downvoted. If your answer is "wrong" for example, or if others "think them as wrong" then it may get downvoted, even though it may be having all the valid sources.

As regards, making "mentioning reasons for downvotes compulsory", many of us (including me) are always in support of implementing that as a rule. But possibly it won't be implemented.

See [this related question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/815/modifications-in-downvoting-system) by Chinmay.

Comment: Agreed with you point. Most of the users gets emotional with any answer if it contradict their believes. Hence they shows their dis-agreeness by down votes even if the answer has shown with all profs and valid reference.

Comment: @Rishabh Yes that's a correct observation. Just ignore the downvotes and keep posting more answers. If you also can read some books then it will help you with the sources part.

Comment: Rickross, according to 2 other answers, it seems that the downvotes have happened as the answer deviated from the actual Qn. Ironically this answer also seems on the same path. :-) Though Your answer is addressing some valid grievances, it is not discussing even 1 bit, why the @Rishabh answer could have been downvotes technically. Though it's accepted this is not a good meta answer.

Comment: I could not get your point. Do you mean i am not answering the Q and yet OP has marked it as selected? @iammilind

Comment: Though it's accepted this is not a good meta answer--- Then what should be done? What's good and what's not- who will decide that? @iammilind

Comment: Also i don't agree that i am not answering the Q even by a bit!... I have addressed his main query. One can get DVs on any answer even if it is supplemented with references if others think them as wrong (this is what my answer is). I am no one to say why he got downvotes. Because that's purely subjective. I won't say you got because there you went wrong. I am not presuming that his answer is either wrong or right.@iammilind

Comment: OP may have accepted it because you echoed his sentiments of victimhood. We all get downvotes, sometimes without reason and out of blue. Of course there may not be a valid reason always. In philosophical site like this, people may often downvote for disagreement and not for inaccuracies. For now the only reason as a layman, I could see is - *"Then, that is quite normal to happen here."* Other one (i.e. "wrong answer") is just a generic example, which also doesn't address the particular Qn. In this case, the downvotes seem due to deviation. I might be wrong, but thought of putting my view.

Comment: OP may have accepted it ---  We don't need to do a post mortem on why OP accepted my answer. We should respect his opinion. just a generic example, which also doesn't address the particular Qn.--- It's ur view that i have not answered the Q. According to OP i have addressed his main query quite aptly it seems. And, that is my view too. @iammilind

Answer (score 3):

The question is actually about understanding How "Never was there a time when I did not exist"? Here 'I' obviously refers to Atman (or say Jivatma) and not the body. And questioner looks confused if never there a time when I didn't exist, then How he did come into being or did he spent many ignorant lives. So, it looks he doesn't understand that due to maya/ignorance, it looks one has many birth but actually the true self is not subjected to transformation (According to Advaita) and/or he is looking for 'why and how he got body' etc. In my opinion, answers to the question: [What is the life cycle of a soul (atma) in Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3568/277) can satisfactorily explain the confusions the asker have.

Now, talking about your answer, actually you spent more time in **proving the everything repeats theory false** i.e your answer debates on that topic which may deviates to what has asked in the question. Also sentences like "But this theory is fake. Here is how..." , "It's Just 2 or 3 exampels is enough to prove this theory is fake." sounds offending to whom believes in that theory. So, kindly speaking, you naughtly challenged or debated for the "everything repeats" theory rather than explaining the actual question. Only last two paragraphs touch the moral of the question.

Talking about what references you should take, it is explained in following posts:

- [What kind of references are valid in answers? Are modern works allowed?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/277)
- [Which scriptures / sources are considered valid?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/806/277)

Note: You may take reference of existing good answers, however some scriptural quotes are preferred and increase the quality of the answer.
e.g your [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21570/277) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21383/277) answers.

So, regarding the questions/issue you've I would suggest:

- Be specific (to the topic/point) while answering the question.
- Avoid using words that may offend to beliefs of users.
- Try to improve your explanation and answer by citing preferred sources.

Comment: The question is actually "Never was there a time when I did not exist"? ----- Exactly, But some thinks we were exist before with same body and same name... That's why I spend time to explain that "I" is not body but instead it's soul. And My whole question was fully focused on proving "I" is not body but soul. Then where I went off-topic in my answer? Can you point where?

Comment: "you spent more time in proving the everything repeats theory false" ------- Well then how else I will prove that "I" is not body but the soul?

Comment: @Rishabh as I said only last two paragraphs looks finely answering questions. And I think no need to prove that "everything repeats" theory is wrong since question doesn't deal with it.

Comment: "But this theory is fake__sounds offending to whom believes in that theory" ----  I didn't mentioned anyone's name, I just put my views without targeting anyone. Then this can't be considered as offensive to anyone since I only shows my views without taking name of any person who beileves in this theory

Comment: "how to prove/explain" @Rishabh you can cite commentaries to that verse of BG. And explain with the help of characteristics of Jivatma and lifecycle of Atman.

Comment: "no need to prove that "everything repeats" theory is wrong since question doesn't deal with it"----- As per my sense its totally deal with this. Since you himself admitted that "I" is soul, not body, but some thinks "I" is body because everything repeats. OP might also believer of the same. Hence proving difference was important IMO.

Comment: @Rishabh I think either you're not getting my point or I'm not getting your point, will discuss in chat room.

Answer (score 1):

I was the one person who [explained the reason for the downvote](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21776/was-there-ever-a-time-when-i-was-not-there#comment62682_21781).

**Because the comments are not for extended discussion**.

[image]

You can ping any user in the chat rooms when you want to discuss the questions or answers which are long.

> But when I contradict his shloka to ask that how this shloka is proving my answer wrong.. then he had no answer. Means, his mentioned shloka wasn't able to prove my answer wrong.

The shloka proved it. I didn't prolong the discussion because comments are not for extended discussion. Explaining how the argument in the answer is wrong would take a lot of comments.Chat rooms are the right place for the discussion.  I added the same  It is not running away because one can answer the questions posted in the comments. There are many other things we do and may not address them instantly. It doesn't mean I lose an I win if one doesn't reply to a comment. So, it is wrong to have prejudice that one can't answer to your questions.

So, I posted [another comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21776/was-there-ever-a-time-when-i-was-not-there#comment62690_21781) to use chat. But you never did. Chat is available in the right side hamburger icon on the top bar.

> 1. How would I know which reference should I take to post answer on this site?

By reading books or some related lierature, you can know which book is related to the question.

> 2. The references I linked was from other answers of this site only, and if those other answers didn't get negative response then why my answer is getting negative response?

We can't expect the same number of upvotes or downvotes the quoted answer has. The number of voters, number of the views and the response changes with question to question. It is not the same for every post. Besides, the quotes in the answers you cited are directly from the scriptures whereas, your answer is purely based on your interpretation. Also, Pandya's [answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/986/5212) gives another reason. Major part of the answer you gave is irrelevant to the question. The answer you gave is like a refutation of the cyclic nature of time rather than the proper addressing of the question. *Your answer would still be a good answer and survive without those references*.

> On what cases an answer with full of references can get down votes?

As explained in the other point, it depends. People downvote on question and answers when there is something factually wrong in the answer or a question. Answers also get downvotes when the answer is purely opinion based. Some may have time for explanation and some don't. So, don't expect an explanation every time you get a couple of downvotes.

Comment: *"Comments are not for extended discussions. Use chat instead."* A very valid point, regardless of this Qn. Here is a [relevant discussion](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/485/1049).

Comment: Yes. I read it and upvoted already. That's a good question. Ironically, that faq post is not known to many and hardly followed.

Comment: Your all points are valid but seems you misjudged my one question. You said _"We can't expect the same number of upvotes or downvotes the quoted answer has"_. But I was not talking about upvotes. Means I am not asking why I didn't get as many upvotes as linked answer got? What I was asking is, Linked answer didn't get downvotes, So all users admits answer is correct. But my answer is same as their, so why user thought my asnwer is not correct since I got downvotes. Question only was, same wordings accepted in linked Q. and same rejected in my answer.

Comment: Besides if you really think your shloka says that everything repeats in same way in every kalpa then why don't you post answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21889/is-reaching-to-next-kalpa-is-common-for-some-persons  You can prove that those persons didn't actually reach to the next kalpa coz in next kalpa everything starts from begining. Story don't contine to next kalpa but instead it start from begining and repeats same as prev.

Comment: I didn't misjudge @Rishabh I gave explanation to that too. You can't expect the same response(upvotes and downvotes) the linked answer has. Those answers are from Puranas whereas your answer is just your observation without any source. Moreover it's a dupe question. They should be closed not answered.  In regards to your question, Swamiji answered it and the people mentioned in the question also have previous births.

Comment: **Swamiji answered it** Where did he answer? Which word or line of his posted paragraph is answering my given question? Pandya and you said I was not on-topic in my most of the answer but I ask you... Is Swami ji is on-topic in his given answer. He didn't add even one word which actually giving answer of my question. But still you guys favoring him because he is highly reputed, have huze repo points and I don't have. I knew since long this site is partial to users. Example is here, Swami didn't receiveed downvote of his off-topic answer but I received of my on-topic answer.

Comment: Your accusation is wrong. Every user receives downvotes irrespective of their reputation. There are numerous examples. For instance, Keshav gets many downvotes. You should see my recent question too. He gave the information about Kalpantara and what happens during that time. It's a partial answer. I will counter question. **If you think that answer is not addressing your question properly, where is your downvote on that answer**? Don't make baseless accusations and blame others that others not downvoting without doing your part. See my points again. Voting changes from person to person.

Comment: **It's a partial answer** No, It wasn't. Because I was asking about those persons who move to next kalpa. And he didn't mentioned about those persons. Whatever he said in his answer, all those things I have already mentioned in beginning lines of my question. **where is your downvote** I don't downvote easily. It's extremely rare when I do downvote on any post. If I feel any posts is offensive then I use to make downvote. Else, if post is partially correct or even if it's totally wrong then also I never put downvote. I just don't like to negate someone's effort until he is offensive in wording